# Can you program Android Apps in a functional language?

Tags: android

Can you program Android Apps in  a functional language?

I meant is it possible to program for Android in a language that was designed from the ground up to be functional? I'm aware that you can use the functional components of an OO or a procedural language to program in a functional style, I was asking whether it would be applicable to use one of the "functional languages" on Android.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: It depends. Most high level languages, Python for example, support multiple programming paradigms, including functional programming. Your question, as it stands is pretty vague and in order to receive a better answer, you'll need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Jeremy WTF. There is a class of languages known as Fucntional Languages (refer Wikipidia for a list) and Android is a specific operating systems. It's hard to see what question could be more specific than this. How is this not a real question?

Comment: @Joel: It does not depend -there is a class of language known as Functional Languages. Python is not one of them (Although it is posisble to adher to Functional Paradigms with Python).

Comment: @mattnz: From the same article "Programming in a functional style can also be accomplished in languages that aren't specifically designed for functional programming." Does the OP want to know if it's _feasible_ or _possible_? It definitely helps to have more context with which to answer a question.

Comment: @mattnz, I know what functional languages are. Just because I commented, doesn't mean I downvoted or voted to close. (I've done neither.) I was simply trying to tease out more information from the OP to get a better idea of what (s)he is really asking. The obvious answer to the question is "yes", but that isn't very useful. The OP hasn't brought anything to the table other than the question itself. I'm sure the OP has a motive for asking, and I think that information would be important when answering.

Comment: Thanks for these answers, I'm glad I'm not the only one who was baffeled by the "be more specific" complaint about an entirely specified question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I meant is it possible to program for Andriod in a language that was designed from the ground up to be functional. I'm aware that you can use the functional components of an OO or a procedural language to program in a functional style, I was asking whether it would be applicable to use one of the "functional languages" on Android. A bit of common sense would not go astray.

Comment: +1 to neutralise the down vote. I do think this is a good and specific question.

Comment: @Cassy 1) Requests for clarifications are a good thing, we can't always guess what the OP has in mind (and we have a ton of questions asking about functional languages, when they mean something else entirely), 2) I've moved your last comment into the question (well, not all of it, just the good parts), 3) Even if a question is closed, you can still edit it, add the missing info and have it removed, 4) Questions that ask for a "yes" or "no" answer usually show lack of research and are discourage.

Comment: Scala has been designed from the beginning as a functional (and object-oriented) language, it also interfaces with Java very well. So it should be possible to program Android applications in Scala (possibly with some Java interface code).

Comment: It's interesting to see the contest here between up-voters and down-voters for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can build Android apps in both Scala and Clojure. The question is would apps produced with these languages be up to "production" standards and I think right now the consensus answer is "not yet"

---

EDIT: Remember I wrote my response almost 3 years ago (as of today). I believe that both Scala and Clojure have come a long way in that time. Plus Kotlin is another good option for building Android apps with a functional language.

Comment: Thanks It was a simple question and I only wanted a simple anwer. Thanks mattnz too, for making me feel like I'm not going insane.

Comment: There is also an option: MonoDroid + Fsharp.

Comment: @Cassy - Unfortunately you have stumbled  is a reason this site is gaining the nickname closers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think right now the consensus answer is "not yet": Some explanation regarding this would be useful. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build Android apps in most (all?) of the languages that can compile down to byte code (JRuby, Scala, Clojure, ...), but the performance is not what you are used to on the Java VM. Dalvik is a different beast, and the various implementations have had to do quite a bit of changes to come up with a decent speed.

Clojure is now [quite performant](http://blog.ndk.io/2015/04/23/state-of-coa.html) on Android (after 5 years), but is still suffering from the same slow startup times as the other scripted languages (like JRuby). Lean Clojure is doing something about this, though.

A commenter mentioned F#, and that is actually a viable option, but a costly one if you are a single developer. The reason being that this usually means developing using Tamarin Studio, a great, but proprietary IDE that compiles .NET apps into native versions for Android and iOS.